# AuthenticationStateProvider returns URL

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a blazor Application
With an API that creates my token and return it to the client as a string.
I use that token to populate my CustomAuthStateProvider.

The problem that I have is each claim type I convert to to the JWT it adds a URL in it.
Please see below:

[image]

Any advise on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These URLs are the constant values of those claims as [defined in the `ClaimTypes` class](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Security.Claims/src/System/Security/Claims/ClaimTypes.cs).

To read those claims you can use:

```cs
var id = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

var name1 = claimsPrincipal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value; // Stefan Mostert

var name2 = claimsPrincipal.Identity.Name; // Stefan Mostert

var role1 = claimsPrincipal.IsInRole("A9E51550-D3C7-4174-B6EA-CE2ADFBE5C82"); // true

var role2 = claimsPrincipal.HasClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "A9E51550-D3C7-4174-B6EA-CE2ADFBE5C82"); // true
```

etc..

[`ClaimsPrincipal` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal?view=net-7.0)